# How to use custom fonts in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to use a custom font in my HTML page.

Below is the HTML code I tried so far with the Font `DENSE`, downloaded from https://www.behance.net/gallery/10231891/Dense-typeface ,
it is saved in the same folder as my HTML file `MyPage.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

@font-face {
  font-family: "Dense-Regular";
  src: url("/Dense-Regular.otf");
}

.Font {
        width: 430px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        color: #cbd9ef;
        font-family: 'Dense-Regular';
        font-size: 140%;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><p class = "Font">This is a paragraph.</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody point out what's wrong? I am newbie in HTML so apologies for any trivial mistake I might have made here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are the `MyPage.html` and the `Dense-Regular.otf` both in the `root` folder of your website?

Comment: Bogaso, if my answer worked for you, would you mind accepting it the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Please remove '/' in the font property 'src'. It should be like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Dense-Regular";
  src: url("Dense-Regular.otf");
}
```

Hope this helps. Go through these links for reference.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
src: url("/Dense-Regular.otf");
```

needs to be this:

```
src: url("Dense-Regular.otf");
```

note the lack of the forward slash in the url.

Answer (score 0):

`<p class = "Font">` should be `<p class="Font">`

Edit:
Are the `MyPage.html` and the `Dense-Regular.otf` both in the `root` folder of your website?

Comment: Whitespace around attributes is purely a style choice and has no syntactical significance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax in CSS3:

```
@font-face {

      font-family: font_name;

      src: location [format];

}
```

Links for details:
1. http://www.brenkoweb.com/tutorials/css3/css3-font-styling/font-styling-in-css3-and-the-atfont-face-rule
2. http://www.brenkoweb.com/tutorials/css3/css3-font-styling/font-descriptors-in-css3

Concretely, in combination with HTML header:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
      src: url("fonts/elegant-icons/ElegantIcons.eot");
      src: url("fonts/elegant-icons/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/elegant-icons/ElegantIcons.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/elegant-icons/ElegantIcons.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/elegant-icons/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons") format("svg");
```

**HTML**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```